# Building std_msgs from source fails

Tags: ros, gentoo, build-from-source, std-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all. I am (attempting) to build ROS Jade from source on Gentoo. I am now at 116 targets built. For some reason, I'm struggling with `std_msgs`.

```
<== Finished processing package [116 of 223]: 'stage'

==> Processing catkin package: 'std_msgs'
==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/std_msgs'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/jade/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/allenh1/catkin_ws/src/std_msgs -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/allenh1/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/jade -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/allenh1/catkin_ws/build_isolated/std_msgs'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/allenh1/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/jade
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/jade
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "3.3.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Found PY_em: /usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/em.py  
-- Using empy: /usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/em.py
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/allenh1/catkin_ws/build_isolated/std_msgs/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-3.3
-- catkin 0.6.14
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;genpy
-- std_msgs: 32 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/allenh1/catkin_ws/build_isolated/std_msgs
==> make -j8 -l8 in '/home/allenh1/catkin_ws/build_isolated/std_msgs'
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Empty
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int8MultiArray
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ColorRGBA
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Float32
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt64
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt64MultiArray
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt16MultiArray
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt32MultiArray
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int8MultiArray
[  0%] [  0%] Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_String
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Float32
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt16MultiArray
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Empty
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ColorRGBA
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt32MultiArray
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt64
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int16
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int64
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt8
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Bool
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Float64
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int16MultiArray
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt64MultiArray
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_String
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MultiArrayLayout
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Header
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int16
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt8
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int64
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Byte
[  0%] Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int8
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Float64
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int64MultiArray
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int32
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Bool
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Float64MultiArray
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int16MultiArray
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Time
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MultiArrayLayout
[  0%] Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Char
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Header
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt32
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Byte
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int8
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int32
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MultiArrayDimension
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int32MultiArray
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Duration
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Float64MultiArray
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int64MultiArray
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ByteMultiArray
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt16
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Time
Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Float32MultiArray
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt32
[  0%] [  0%] Scanning dependencies of target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt8MultiArray
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MultiArrayDimension
Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Char
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Duration
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Int32MultiArray
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt16
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ByteMultiArray
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Float32MultiArray
[  0%] Built target _std_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_UInt8MultiArray
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  2%] [  3%] [  5%] [  5%] [  5%] [  6%] [  6%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Empty.msg
Generating C++ code from std_msgs/String.msg
Generating C++ code from std_msgs/UInt64MultiArray.msg
Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Empty.msg
Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Duration.msg
Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/String.msg
Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Empty.msg
Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Empty
[  8%] [  8%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/String.msg
Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/String
[  8%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/UInt64MultiArray.msg
[  9%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Duration.msg
[  9%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/UInt64MultiArray
[ 10%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/UInt64MultiArray.msg
[ 11%] [ 12%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Duration.msg
Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/UInt32MultiArray.msg
[ 12%] [ 14%] [ 14%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/UInt32MultiArray.msg
Generating C++ code from std_msgs/UInt64.msg
Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.msg
[ 15%] [ 16%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Int8MultiArray.msg
Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Duration
[ 17%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/UInt32MultiArray
[ 17%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/UInt32MultiArray.msg
[ 18%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.msg
[ 19%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Float64MultiArray
[ 20%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.msg
[ 21%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/UInt64
[ 22%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/UInt64.msg
[ 22%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Int8MultiArray.msg
[ 23%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/UInt64.msg
[ 23%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Int8MultiArray
[ 24%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/UInt16MultiArray
[ 24%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/UInt16MultiArray.msg
[ 25%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Header.msg
[ 26%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/UInt16MultiArray.msg
[ 27%] [ 28%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Int64.msg
Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Int16MultiArray.msg
[ 29%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Int8MultiArray.msg
[ 31%] [ 31%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Float32.msg
Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Header
[ 32%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Header.msg
[ 32%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/UInt16MultiArray.msg
[ 33%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Int64
[ 34%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Int64.msg
[ 35%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Header.msg
[ 35%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/UInt8.msg
[ 36%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Bool.msg
[ 36%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Int16MultiArray
[ 37%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Float64.msg
[ 38%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout.msg
[ 38%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Int16MultiArray.msg
[ 38%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Byte.msg
[ 39%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Int64.msg
[ 40%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Float32
[ 41%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Float32.msg
[ 42%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Int16MultiArray.msg
[ 43%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/UInt8
[ 44%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Int8.msg
[ 45%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Int64MultiArray.msg
[ 46%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/UInt8.msg
[ 47%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Bool
[ 48%] [ 49%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Float32.msg
Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Int32.msg
[ 49%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Int16.msg
[ 50%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Time.msg
[ 50%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Float64
[ 51%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Bool.msg
[ 51%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/UInt8.msg
[ 52%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout
[ 52%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Float64.msg
[ 53%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Bool.msg
[ 54%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Char.msg
[ 55%] [ 56%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Byte
Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Int8
[ 57%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Int64MultiArray
[ 57%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Int32
[ 58%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout.msg
[ 59%] [ 60%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/UInt32.msg
Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Float64.msg
[ 61%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Int16
[ 62%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Time
[ 63%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Char
[ 63%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/UInt32
[ 64%] [ 65%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Int32MultiArray
[ 66%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Byte.msg
Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout.msg
[ 67%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension
[ 68%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/ColorRGBA
[ 68%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/ByteMultiArray
[ 69%] [ 70%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/UInt16
[ 71%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Int32MultiArray.msg
Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Int8.msg
[ 71%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Byte.msg
[ 72%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/Float32MultiArray
[ 73%] Generating Python from MSG std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray
[ 74%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Int8.msg
[ 74%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension.msg
[ 75%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/ColorRGBA.msg
[ 76%] [ 77%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Int64MultiArray.msg
Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Int64MultiArray.msg
[ 77%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Int32.msg
[ 78%] Generating Python msg __init__.py for std_msgs
[ 79%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Int32.msg
[ 79%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Int16.msg
[ 80%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Int16.msg
[ 81%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Time.msg
[ 82%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Char.msg
[ 82%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 82%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/UInt32.msg
[ 83%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Time.msg
[ 84%] [ 85%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Char.msg
Generating C++ code from std_msgs/ByteMultiArray.msg
[ 86%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Int32MultiArray.msg
[ 87%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension.msg
[ 88%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/UInt16.msg
[ 89%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/ColorRGBA.msg
[ 89%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.msg
[ 90%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/UInt32.msg
[ 90%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/ByteMultiArray.msg
[ 91%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/UInt16.msg
[ 92%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.msg
[ 93%] Generating EusLisp code from std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray.msg
[ 94%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Int32MultiArray.msg
[ 95%] Generating EusLisp manifest code for std_msgs
[ 96%] [ 96%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension.msg
Generating C++ code from std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray.msg
[ 97%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/ColorRGBA.msg
[ 98%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/ByteMultiArray.msg
[ 99%] [ 99%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/UInt16.msg
Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.msg
[100%] Generating Lisp code from std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray.msg
[100%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[100%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/geneus/geneus_main.py", line 133, in genmain
    if pkg_map.has_key('geneus'):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
ERROR:  'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
CMakeFiles/std_msgs_generate_messages_eus.dir/build.make:298: recipe for target '/home/allenh1/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs/share/roseus/ros/std_msgs/manifest.l' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/allenh1/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs/share/roseus/ros/std_msgs/manifest.l] Error 3
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1369: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/std_msgs_generate_messages_eus.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/std_msgs_generate_messages_eus.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'std_msgs': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/jade/env.sh', 'make', '-j8', '-l8']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/allenh1/catkin_ws/build_isolated/std_msgs && /opt/ros/jade/env.sh make -j8 -l8

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213283/building-std_msgs-from-source-fails/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Easy fix. Sorry everyone.

```
$ cd src
$ rm -rf geneus
$ https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/geneus
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0